# How to connect tops and bass bins

Tags: equipment, connector

I'm DJing all kinds of parties, house parties, and events the last year or so.

I have a set of Prosound 500w passive tops and a Prosound 1600w amp. Not great but does the trick.

I'm using a Numark cdmix 1 as my CD mixer. Using the spare channel for my laptop, cds for back up

I bought a Behringer ep2500w amp, their recently great amp.

I'm using the Behringer amp with the tops for the mean time, but I want to buy subs/bass bins.

I was looking at these [Behringer VP1800 S](http://www.thomann.de/ie/behringer_vp1800_s.htm) -- I want a bit more power for bigger places.

My question is:

I want to run the tops of the Prosound amp and the two bins of the Behringer amp, but how would I go about it?  Do I need a crossover?  How would I connect everything up?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will need a crossover.  You would run the signal to the crossover which will send the frequencies below 200Hz to one amp and those above 200Hz to the other.

Answer (score 0):

As Benji says, you will need a high power crossover if you just want to use the amp you have, but be aware that the bass bins will use a lot of the available power so the tops will not have as much headroom as before, so you have the potential to lose sound quality.

If you have the option, use a separate amp for bass and treble, or at least an active mixing desk which has high and low pass filters - that way you will get better clarity of both the bass and treble.